# CSS adjacent selector doesn't work

Tags: html, css, sass

Consider I have this DOM,

```
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Hover to change color</button>
</div>
```

I want to select `p` from `button` why below css doesn't work?

```
#banner-message {
  button {
    & + p {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code given is not working as you are traversing previous siblings. CSS selectors work for next siblings. There is no previous sibling selector. You can refer to the accepted answer for [Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector) for more information. Otherwise you will have to change the markup as mentioned by @Andy Aldo.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `&`. By the way, in your SCSS, you're selecting `button + p` but in your markup it's `p + button`. See [here](http://jsbin.com/rebihokone/edit?html,css,output) for demo

Comment: you don't change my DOM lol

Comment: oops, my bad. as the others may have highlighted, as of now there is no way to traverse back.

Answer (score 0):

With the + selector, you are selecting the `<p>` AFTER the button...
See this: https://jsfiddle.net/8y2mstbo/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with css to select previous element. so you should try script for this or you should change the structure.